# How to compare two CSV's with Json's fields

Tags: java, json, csv, arraylist

I have a work to compare two CSV's that the fields are : string json object json object date string string How to open the files and compare them? I tried till now for one CSV first of all these methods, so whats next?:

```
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Collection<Object> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    String filePath = ".\\sheet.csv";

    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath));
    CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
    {
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            String name = csvRecord.get("name");
            String email = csvRecord.get("jobSpecification");
            String phone = csvRecord.get("assignedProject");
            String country = csvRecord.get("lastUpdated");
            String id = csvRecord.get("id");
            String comments = csvRecord.get("comments");

            Data row = new Data(name, email, phone, country, id, comments);
            
            lines.add(row);

        }
    }
    for (Object d : lines) {
        System.out.println(d.toString());
    }
```

}

and the object:

```
public class Data {
String name;
String email ;
String phone ;
String country;
String id;
String comments;

public Data(String name, String email, String phone, String country, String id, String comments) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.country = country;
    this.id = id;
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name: "+name+" "+" email: "+email+" phone: "+phone+" country: "+country+" id: "+id+" comments: "+comments;
}
```

}

so now I think that left only the compare
the CSV(that i made) looks like [these](https://ibb.co/SR7Tmgb)

Comment: Not really clear for what you are trying to accomplish here. However, it may be better to have: `Collection<Data> lines = new ArrayList<>();` and `lines.add(new Data(name, email, phone, country, id, comments));`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd i'm trying to compare cetween 2 csv's that each csv have two fields that are actualy jsons, the rest of the fields are data, string, ints,
so i made an object from each row..but what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two CSV's I suggest to use equals method on class which contains csv's fields and iterate these files line by line,
but you have to implement own equals & hashcode methods in Data class.

There is one thing you need to consider - comparison of two jsons is not so easy, there are many libraries, but almost all libraries use strict comparison method, this means that comparing two
jsons with different field order, or nested field order, or nested array items order will results in false negative comparison between these json objects.

The library that allows lenient comparison is jsonassert library:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Below you can find basic implementation, it checks if two JSONs are deeply equals (regardless the fields order, arrays items order) - used *comments* field as example.

```
//Data class
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Data data = (Data) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, data.name) &&
            Objects.equals(email, data.email) &&
            Objects.equals(phone, data.phone) &&
            Objects.equals(country, data.country) &&
            Objects.equals(id, data.id) &&
            deepJSONsEquals(comments, data.comments);
}

private boolean deepJSONsEquals(String firstJson, String secondJson) {
    try {
        return JSONCompare.compareJSON(firstJson, secondJson, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT).passed();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, email, phone, country, id, comments);
}
```

MainApp class:

```
List<Data> linesFromFirstCsv = new ArrayList<>();
List<Data> linesFromSecondCsv = new ArrayList<>();

// add here line by line values from csv to relevant lists. (create Data objects)

    if(linesFromFirstCsv.size() == linesFromSecondCsv.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(linesFromFirstCsv.size(), linesFromSecondCsv.size()); i++) {
            System.out.println(linesFromFirstCsv.get(i).equals(linesFromSecondCsv.get(i)));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("not equals");
    }
```

This will return a **true** result in comparison of example jsons passed as *comments* value(different field order in array, and array items order):

```
{
    "comments":
    [
        {
        "timestamp": 123123123,
        "id": "1212",
        "body": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
        "body": "lorem ipsum2",
        "id": "1213",
        "timestamp": 123123125
        },
        {
        "id": "1214",
        "body": "lorem ipsum3",
        "timestamp": 123123129
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "comments":
    [
        {
        "id": "1213",
        "body": "lorem ipsum2",
        "timestamp": 123123125
        },
        {
        "id": "1212",
        "body": "lorem ipsum",
        "timestamp": 123123123
        },
        {
        "id": "1214",
        "body": "lorem ipsum3",
        "timestamp": 123123129
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you
Still in few lines i changed the fields and it says it is True.
Strange